# Authorization with Rails like .NET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

When I work with .NET, I use to manage the authorization with a filter, something like:

```
[MyAuthorizationFilter(EnumRole.Admin)]
public ActionResult DoSomethingOnlyForAdministrators() {
//...
}
```

How could I work with this on RoR? I want to do something like this: when an action is called, some filter or class would be called and check if has a logged user, if that user has the needed role... thinks like that.

Is there a way to do this? I want to do manually. Since I'm starting with RoR, I want to learn about before use some created gem to do the trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RailsCasts has a couple of episodes on authorization from scratch:

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=authorization

You might also check out the popular options for authorization in Rails:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization

Even if you want to develop your own, you can look at the internals, tests, and example apps of these.

Comment: Thanks, these videos helped to me a lot!